# AWS EC2: Switch Instance when status check fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created two instances in AWS (one is Live & other is Backup). My website is hosted on Live Instance. what I want to do is, if Live instance Status check fails, then it should switch to Backup Instance. Is there any automated process to achieve the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is not a good idea to keep one instance idle and pay for it. Put them under an [Elastic Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elastic-load-balancing.html) and start using both of them. The ELB [health check](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-healthchecks.html) will automatically remove the instances that stop working. Then you can continue to monitor the number of healthy instances under your ELB with [AWS Cloud Watch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-cloudwatch-metrics.html) and setup an alert - to get an email when something happens or you can even [autoscale](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_SetUpASLBApp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Liviu Costea's answer is the best way to go. If you insist on only keeping one active server at a time, and you are using Route53 for your DNS, then you can use [Route 53 Health Checks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html) to switch the domain name resolution from your primary server to your secondary server in the case that your primary server goes out of service.